# Throw error if stubbed function was called with the wrong arguments using Sinon

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

Currently, `sinon` is able to create a stub which will return a given object if there is a match of parameters:

```js
const methodStub = stub(service, 'method').withArgs("param1").returns("OK");
```

You can even assert that the right parameters were called:

```js
expect(methodStub).to.have.been.calledWith("param1");
```

Question: Since you explicitly said your stubbed method will only allow `param1`, is there a way to make the assertion **without explicitly using the calledWith method?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is quite right to say "your stubbed method will only allow `"param1"`". Instead, you have stubbed your method only for the case in which it is called with the argument `"param1"` and you have defined that stub to return `"OK"`. This doesn't disallow your code to call the method with any other arguments, however, when it is called with anything other than `"param1"` it will return `undefined` because you haven't stubbed a return value for any other arguments.

To your specific question about using `calledWith`:

As you have constrained your stub with `.withArgs("param1")` then, as your question anticipates, asserting that it has been called with `"param1"` is equivalent to asserting that it has been called at all.

[sinon-chai](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/sinon-chai/) has a `.called` property which would behave the same as your code without using `.calledWith` - it will throw an AssertionError if `service.method` is *not* called with `"param1"`.

`expect(methodStub).to.have.been.called`

Answer (score 0):

Add .callsFake(throwError) first in the chain.

See https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/lock-down-sinon-stub/ (no affiliation!)

Which advocates doing what you asking to do, and explains how to do it.

Comment: any affiliation to this blog? ([/help/promotion](/help/promotion))